# How to control screen behavior when suspending Vim with Ctrl-Z

Tags: terminal, vim

I frequently suspend and resume Vim with ctrl-z and fg, respectively.  In all the OS/Terminal combinations I've used, whatever they were, the behavior was I would see whatever was on the screen before starting Vim.

At work, I've recently been moved to a newer CentOs host for the development work I do (no Internet access).

Now, suspending puts the cursor at the bottom of the screen, leaving the lines from the Vim session above it.  I'd like to change back to the behavior I've become accustomed to -- how do I control this behavior?  Not sure what information is needed (I'm not good at *configuring* vim...).  It's a newer version of CentOS (probably 5, previously 4) and bash.

Comment: That has nothing with do with vim, but with whether your terminal emulator supports the `smcup`/`rmcup` escapes and whether they're enabled and "published" in the terminfo database. They're not supported in the linux console. AFAIK vim will always use them if available. Add info about what terminal you're using together with the output of `infocmp` run inside it.

Comment: A program where they're are disabled by default is the `screen` terminal multiplexer. If you're using it, adding `altscreen on` in your `~/.screenrc` should re-enable it.